# Gimp installation failed due to depedency

Tags: gimp

I want to install gimp in 13.10. I follow these procedure to install gimp.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

But after i update the system, when i go for the last command.(sudo apt-get install gimp)
It show this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.9.1.119-build~33915~145295a~saucy0~ppa) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.9.1.119-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can i install the gimp and resolve the error. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure to install gimp is `sudo apt-get install gimp`

When using a third party repository you are mostly on youw own and if there is any issue with the repository you must contact with the person that maintains it.

Comment: When install gimp, the above error is shown. What i cant understand.

Comment: No, you added a third party repository and installed gimp from there.